# How to create pathfield generically so that it handles all extensions in cq5

Tags: aem

When we take a pathfield value in jsp, need to provide harcoded ".html" or ".pdf". 
Is there any way to make pathfield generic, hence no need to provide hard coded extensions? So if a user selects .pdf it will display a pdf file and if user selects .html it will open a html file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a OOB way to do this. Alternatively, You can create a script/custom jstl tag which take path as input, load resource and find out resource type and generate path with correct extn as output.

Call this script from all your components which generate links.

Another option is you extend com.day.cq.rewriter.pipeline.RequestRewriter and in rewriteLink() function write your logic to set correct extn.